# Use Wordpress' Excerpt with a "more" link?

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress' documentation suggests adding the following to functions.php to enable what I want to do:

```
function new_excerpt_more($post) {
    return '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . 'Read the Rest...' . '</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

As per: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

But when I add this to functions.php, and I attempt to use it, I don't see the more link. Here is how I try to use it:

```
the_excerpt(__('(more...)'));
```

I've also tried:

```
the_excerpt();
```

---

Update: I've tried the following, but it either returns an error (if no arguments), or it doesn't display any excerpt or anything (if an argument):

```
function new_excerpt_more($excerpt) {
    $link = get_permalink();
    $title = the_title('','',false);
    $ahref = '<a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">more...</a>';
    return str_replace('[...]', $ahref, $excerpt);
}
add_filter('wp_trim_excerpt', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
function new_excerpt_more($output) {
    return $output . '<p><a href="'. get_permalink() . '">' . 'Read the Rest...' . '</a></p>';
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Works with:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function new_excerpt_more( ) {
return ' <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">ReadMore</a>';
 }
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

works with

```
the_excerpt();
```

Comment: This is the only one to strip [...]

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
function new_excerpt_more($excerpt) {
    $link = get_permalink();
    $title = the_title('','',false);
    $ahref = '<a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">more...</a>';
    return str_replace('[...]', $ahref, $excerpt);
}
add_filter('wp_trim_excerpt', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Comment: Thanks much for trying. I get blank results when I try: "<?php new_excerpt_more("more..."); ?>" and I get an error when I try "<?php new_excerpt_more(); ?>". The error I get is "Missing argument 1 for new_excerpt_more()". I do not get blank results when using "the_excerpt();".

Answer (score 0):

A much better solution for people using WordPress 2.9 and higher is to utilize the excerpt_more filter. Using the code below should help you accomplish what you need.

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">Read More</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

Additional information can be found in the WordPress Codex here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#Remove_.5B....5D_string_using_Filters

Answer (score -1):

I believe that wordpress recommends using 'the_content()' over 'the_excerpt()'

Hopefully this will help, a simple example could be on your page.php putting something like this:

```
    <?php  global $more;    
       $more = 0;
       the_content("Read the Rest of " . the_title('', '', false)); ?>
```

Comment: I think they say "sometimes it's more meaningful". Also, I think using it nullifies the excerpt input field?

Comment: Yes, you are correct - I misspoke. I think I misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish.