# Need "Read More" button to show when excerpt field is filled out in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Need "Read More" button to show when excerpt field is filled out in wordpress. Currently the button only shows up when excerpt field is empty as it grabs the first paragraph of the post. I created a child theme. I think by changing this excerpt.php file from the parent theme may be the way to go but let me know...

```
<?php
if( ! function_exists( 'newslite_excerpt_length' ) ) :

    /**
     * Excerpt length
     *
     * @since  newslite 1.0.0
     *
     * @param null
     * @return int
     */
    function newslite_excerpt_length( $length ){
        global $newslite_customizer_all_values;
        $excerpt_length = $newslite_customizer_all_values['newslite-excerpt-length'];
        if ( empty( $excerpt_length) ) {
            $excerpt_length = $length;
        }
        return absint( $excerpt_length );

    }

endif;
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'newslite_excerpt_length', 999 );


if ( ! function_exists( 'newslite_implement_read_more' ) ) :

    /**
     * Implement read more in excerpt.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @param string $more The string shown within the more link.
     * @return string The excerpt.
     */
    function newslite_implement_read_more( $more ) {

        $flag_apply_excerpt_read_more = apply_filters( 'newslite_filter_excerpt_read_more', true );
        if ( true !== $flag_apply_excerpt_read_more ) {
            return $more;
        }

        $output = $more;
        $read_more_text = __('continue reading','newslite');
        if ( ! empty( $read_more_text ) ) {
            $output = ' <div class="read-more-text"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" class="read-more">' . esc_html( $read_more_text ) . '</a></div>';
            $output = apply_filters( 'newslite_filter_read_more_link' , $output );
        }
        return $output;

    }

endif;

add_action( 'excerpt_more', 'newslite_implement_read_more' );
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3167570/5641669

Comment: Worked - Thank you!